# Add a label to show the Text that was entered in an Entry within an Android Keyboard

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI App I wanted to display the Text that a user inserts in an Entry to display in a Label directly in the Android Keyboard.

I started with the following try and implemented an own `EntryHandler` for it:

```cs
#if ANDROID

using Android.Content;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget;
using Microsoft.Maui.Handlers;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class EntryKeyboardHandler : EntryHandler
    {
        private TextView textView;

        protected override void ConnectHandler(AppCompatEditText platformView)
        {
            base.ConnectHandler(platformView);

            textView = new TextView(Context);
            textView.TextAlignment = Android.Views.TextAlignment.Center;
            textView.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
            textView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.LightGray);
            //textView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;

            var windowLayoutParams = new WindowManagerLayoutParams(
                WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent,
                WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent,
                WindowManagerTypes.ApplicationPanel,
                WindowManagerFlags.NotFocusable |
                WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchModal |
                WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits,
                Android.Graphics.Format.Translucent);

            windowLayoutParams.Gravity = GravityFlags.Bottom | GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal;

            var windowManager = (WindowManager)Context.GetSystemService(Context.WindowService);
            //windowManager.AddView(textView, windowLayoutParams);

            platformView.TextChanged += PlatformView_TextChanged;
        }

        private void PlatformView_TextChanged(object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            textView.Text = e.Text.ToString();
        }

        protected override void DisconnectHandler(AppCompatEditText platformView)
        {
            base.DisconnectHandler(platformView);

            var parentView = (ViewGroup)textView.Parent;
            parentView.RemoveView(textView);
        }
    }
}

#endif
```

I am not sure if I am on the right track with it, but how would I be able to add or display this `TextView` instance on the Keyboard of this `EntryHandler`?

I tried with the `windowManager` but this was actually not possible for me to add it.

Is there a common way to get a `Lable` or `TextView` into the **Android** Keyboard?

Comment: Can you visually show me what you want, I have a feeling you might be overcomplicating things here

Comment: The problem I have, is that when the Keyboard is displayed, some Entry’s might be not visible and covered by the Keyboard. So, I thought it might be a good idea to see at least what is entered in an Entry (while the user is typing). So, if a user types „153“, I want to see this value above or below the Keyboard in a Label. On iOS it is possible to add such a label to a custom Toolbar. I am looking for something similar on Android

Comment: Why are you not just adjusting your screen based on the Entry control to never be hidden behind keyboards?

Comment: Sound also interesting. How could I do that?

Comment: Can you check this video, see if this helps and I can add an answer as well if you would like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bIsGFx7jGcM&ab_channel=GeraldVersluis

Comment: @FreakyAli - I went on with my approach and posted an answer below showing how this could be solved using an `IKeyboardService` with a `GlobalLayoutListener` that shows a `Popup` window with the text that is currently entered. This is presented just below the Android `Keyboard`. If you have ideas for improvements, just let me know

Comment: Interesting stuff thanks for tagging on this

Comment: What I currently don’t know is, how to get it into the toolbar that is normally above when you don’t have a numeric keyboard. There, you can normally find elements like Emojis and so on. Any idea?

Comment: No unfortunately never done something like this!

Answer (score 1):

I want to answer my question by an implementation of a custom `KeyboardService` that provides an Overlay `PopupWindow` to show the currently entered Text in the activated Android `Keyboard`. This is achieved via `GlobalLayoutListener` that checks if the `Keyboard` is activated and determines the `EditText` that currently has the focus. The Text of this `EditText` (Entry) is shown in the `Overlay` provided via `KeyboardOverlayService`:

To achieve this, I added the following file `KeyboardService` in the Android Platform Folder:
`...\Platforms\Android\ControlHandler\..`

**IKeyboardOverlayService.cs**:

```cs
namespace MyApp.Platforms.Android.ControlHandler
{
    public interface IKeyboardOverlayService
    {
        void ShowOverlay(string text);
        void HideOverlay();
    }
}
```

**KeyboardOverlayService.cs**:

```cs
#if ANDROID

using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Application = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application;
using View = Android.Views.View;
using Graphics = Android.Graphics;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MyApp.Platforms.Android.ControlHandler.KeyboardOverlayService))]
namespace MyApp.Platforms.Android.ControlHandler
{
    public class KeyboardOverlayService : IKeyboardOverlayService
    {
        private PopupWindow overlayPopup;
        private TextView textView;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private View view;

        public void ShowOverlay(string text)
        {
            var context = Application.Current?.Handler?.MauiContext?.Context;
            if (context == null) return;

            // Initialize inflater and View only once
            if (inflater == null || view == null)
            {
                inflater = LayoutInflater.From(context);
                view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.overlay_layout, null);
                textView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.overlayTextView);
            }

            textView.Text = text;

            if (overlayPopup == null)
            {
                overlayPopup = new PopupWindow(context);
                overlayPopup.ContentView = view;
                overlayPopup.Width = 400;
                overlayPopup.Height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent;
                overlayPopup.SetBackgroundDrawable(new Graphics.Drawables.ColorDrawable(Graphics.Color.Transparent));
                overlayPopup.OutsideTouchable = false;                          // Prevents that the Overlay is hidden when touch registered outside
            }

            var activity = Application.Current.Windows[0]?.Handler?.MauiContext?.Context?.GetActivity();
            if (activity != null)
            {
                DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                activity.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(displayMetrics);
                int screenWidth = displayMetrics.WidthPixels;
                
                int xPos = (screenWidth - overlayPopup.Width) / 2;              // Center the Overlay                
                int yPos = -50;                                                 // The higher the value the lower the Overlay should be displayed

                // Position the PopupWindow, only if not already displayed
                if (!overlayPopup.IsShowing)
                {
                    overlayPopup.ShowAtLocation(activity.Window.DecorView.RootView, GravityFlags.Bottom | GravityFlags.Start, xPos, yPos);
                }
            }
        }

        public void HideOverlay()
        {
            overlayPopup?.Dismiss();
        }
    }
}

#endif
```

**MainProgram.cs**:

In the `MainProgram.cs` we can register this `IKeyboardOverlayService` to get this `Service` from other places:

```cs
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder
        .UseMauiApp<App>()
        .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
        {
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
        })

    ...

#if ANDROID
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IKeyboardOverlayService, KeyboardOverlayService>();
#endif

    ...

    return builder.Build();
}
```

**Layouting of the Overlay**:

For the layout of the `Overlay` I added a `overlay_layout.xml` file with constants to layout the content of the `Overlay` (e.g. `textColor` and `background`) in the **Android Platform Resources Layout** folder:
`..\Platforms\Android\Resources\layout\overlay_layout.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#F0F0F3">
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/overlayTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#1C1C1C"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
    
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.cs**:

In `..\Platforms\Android\MainActivity.cs` we can register a `GlobalLayoutListener` that listens to the `Keyboard` being opened and closed and shows/hides the `Overlay` correspondingly when the Android Keyboard is visible or disappears:

```cs
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using MyApp.Platforms.Android.ControlHandler;
using Microsoft.Maui.Platform;

namespace MyApp;

//[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
[Activity(Theme = "@style/CustomSplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    private ViewTreeObserver.IOnGlobalLayoutListener _globalLayoutListener;
    private Android.Views.View _rootView;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        // Just initialize the Root-View without adding a GlobalLayoutListener here (will be done in the OnResume method)
        _rootView = (ViewGroup)((ViewGroup)FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content)).GetChildAt(0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the activity will start interacting with the user. At this point, the activity is moved to the top of the activity stack, becoming visible and interactive.
    /// This method registers the GlobalLayoutListener if it hasn't been registered already. This is essential to ensure that layout changes, such as keyboard visibility changes,
    /// are monitored when the activity is in the foreground, enhancing user experience by adjusting the layout or performing specific actions in response to these changes.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();

        // Register the GlobalLayoutListener, in case the Activity is resumed
        if (_globalLayoutListener == null)
        {
            _globalLayoutListener = new GlobalLayoutListener(_rootView, this);
            _rootView.ViewTreeObserver.AddOnGlobalLayoutListener(_globalLayoutListener);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the system is about to start resuming a previous activity. This method is typically used to commit unsaved changes to persistent data, stop animations
    /// and other things that may be consuming CPU, etc. Implementations of this method must be very quick because the next activity will not be resumed until this method returns.
    /// Here, it ensures that the GlobalLayoutListener is removed to prevent memory leaks and to stop monitoring layout changes when the activity is not visible to the user.
    /// This cleanup is crucial for resource management and to avoid unnecessary work when the app is running in the background.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();

        // Remove the GlobalLayoutListener to make sure we do not create Memory Leaks
        if (_globalLayoutListener != null)
        {
            _rootView.ViewTreeObserver.RemoveOnGlobalLayoutListener(_globalLayoutListener);
            _globalLayoutListener = null; // Make sure we can try it again in then OnResume method
        }
    }

    private class GlobalLayoutListener : Java.Lang.Object, ViewTreeObserver.IOnGlobalLayoutListener
    {
        private readonly Context _context;
        private IKeyboardOverlayService _keyboardOverlayService;

        public GlobalLayoutListener(Android.Views.View view, Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
            _keyboardOverlayService = App.Current.Handler.MauiContext.Services.GetService<IKeyboardOverlayService>();
        }

        public bool IsKeyboardVisible()
        {
            var context = _context;
            var activity = context.GetActivity();
            var window = activity.Window;
            var windowInsets = window.DecorView.RootWindowInsets;
            var imeVisible = windowInsets != null && windowInsets.IsVisible(WindowInsets.Type.Ime());

            return imeVisible;
        }

        public void OnGlobalLayout()
        {
            if (IsKeyboardVisible())
            {
                var activity = _context.GetActivity();
                var focusedView = activity.CurrentFocus;

                // Get the Text of the EditText ("Entry") that is currently focused
                // and for which the currently visible Keyboard is opened
                if (focusedView is EditText editText)
                {
                    var text = editText.Text;

                    _keyboardOverlayService.ShowOverlay(text);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _keyboardOverlayService.HideOverlay();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will provide the `Overlay` below the Android Keyboard and looks as follows with the configuration from the `overlay_layout.xml` from above and can be changed to your needs:

[image]